# Modifying a list in place: Calculating a sieve of primes in a python list

Tags: python, list

Problem number 10 of Project Euler asks us to calculate the sum of all primes below 2,000,000.

My algorithm for the same is:

1. Construct a sieve for numbers under 2,000,000
2. Sum all the numbers in the sieve.

I am not comfortable with the code creating multiple lists instead of performing computations over the same list.

Given below is my code:

```
def main(number_above):
list_of_numbers = list(range(number_above))
list_of_numbers = calculate_sieve(list_of_numbers)
print summation_of_primes(list_of_numbers)

def calculate_sieve(list_of_numbers):

    for prime in list_of_numbers:

        if prime >= 2 and prime != 'C':
            multiple = 2
            while multiple * prime < len(list_of_numbers):
                list_of_numbers[ prime * multiple ] = 'C'
                multiple += 1
    return list_of_numbers


def summation_of_primes(list_of_numbers):
    summation = 0
    for element in list_of_numbers:
        if element != 'C':
            summation += element
    return summation - 1
```

The steps in which the lists are created:

- First, a list is created of numbers in range(2,000,000)
- Second, this list is passed on to the calculate_sieve function which cancels all composites.
- Then, the calculate_sieve function returns a list to the main function.
- Finally, this list is passed on to the summation function.

**Is python operating on the same list in place, or does it hold more than one list at a time?
If it is creating multiple copies of the list, is there a way to minimize memory usage by operating on the list in place?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is python operating on the same list in place?

Yes, mostly.

- passing a list as an argument to a function does not create a new list.
- modifying elements in a list does not create a new list.
- returning a list from a function does not create a new list.

The only code you have that may potentially create a duplicate list is this line:

```
list_of_numbers = list(range(number_above))
```

In Python 2.7 and below, `range` already returns a list. Calling `list` on the result will create a second list. You can safely just write `list_of_numbers = range(number_above)` and save yourself a little memory.

In 3.X, `range` returns a `range` object, so the `list` call is necessary there, if you want to subsequently do assignment, like `list_of_numbers[ prime * multiple ] = 'C'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it very easily:

```
In [1]: def some_func(seq):
   ...:     seq.append(1)
   ...:     

In [2]: s = []

In [3]: some_func(s)

In [4]: s
Out[4]: [1]
```

Since `s` got modified `some_func` cannot operate on a copy of it.

---

Identifiers (or variables) in python are always *references* to an object. They are **not** memory locations. They are *names* to an object. When you pass an object to a function the arguments simply creates a new reference to that object, so there's no copying involved.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all your computations are performed on the same list in place, a list is mutable and it is passed by reference, hence I believe in your case there will only be one list in memory at the same time.